# Distinguish ranges in array, and expand them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, range

I need to distinguish ranges in array, and expand it. I'm using JavaScript.

Ex:

```
var arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"];
```

And the desired output is

```
var output =["1", "6", "4", "5", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15"];
```

I currently have the script to expand a certain range. I'm having a hard time in identifying ranges in the array:

```
var range = "1-6";
range = str.split("-");

start = parseInt(range[0]);
end = parseInt(range[1]);

var rangeArray = [];

for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
    rangeArray.push(i);
}
console.log(rangeArray);
```

Comment: I guess you have to iterate that array somehow, can't you simply check the element for a containing `-` to see if it's a range? `element.includes("-")` (true when range element)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. Loop over the array and check if the item contains `-` symbol, if yes then split it and get the ranges. Loop over the ranges and add each item into the array. Otherwise just add that item. For this logic you can also create an helper function which returns an array from the given range and `concat` with the original array that range.

```js
const arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"];
let newArray = [];

function getRange(start, count) {
   const arr = [];
   for(let i = start; i <= count; i++) {
       arr.push(i.toString());
   }  
   return arr;
}

arr.forEach(item => {
  if(item.includes('-')) {    
    const [start, end] = item.split('-').map(n => parseInt(n));
    newArray = newArray.concat(getRange(start,end));
  } else {
    newArray.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Also you can do this using `reduce` method

```js
const arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"];

function getRange(start, count) {
   const arr = [];
   for(let i = start; i <= count; i++) {
       arr.push(i.toString());
   }   
   return arr;
}

const newArray = arr.reduce( (arr, item) => {
  if(item.includes('-')) {  
    const [start, end] = item.split('-').map(n => parseInt(n));
    arr = arr.concat(getRange(start, end));
  } else {
    arr.push(item);
  }  
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code to make a `splitRanges` function that return all the numbers in arange, and looped over the initial array and used this function to extract all the ranges in each iteration:

```js
var arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"]

function splitRanges(rangeStr) {
  var range = rangeStr.split("-");
  var start = parseInt(range[0]);
  var end = parseInt(range[1]);
  var rangeArray = [];

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    rangeArray.push(""+i+"");
  }
  return rangeArray;
}

var output = [];

arr.forEach(function(r){
    if(r.indexOf("-")>-1){
      output = output.concat(splitRanges(r));
    }else
      output.push(r);
});
console.log(output);
```

**Explanation:**

This code loops over the initial array, and in each iteration check if it's a range pass this value to the `splitRanges`  function and `concat` the result to our output array otherwise just `push` the value in the `output` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
let arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"];
let out = [];
const range = (start, end) => Array.from({length: (end - start)}, (v, k) => k + start);
arr.forEach(item => {
   let splitted = item.split('-');
    if(splitted.length > 1) {
        out.push(...range(parseInt(splitted[0]), parseInt(splitted[1]) + 1));
    } else {
        out.push(parseInt(item))
    }
})
console.log('out: ', out); // [1, 6, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can distinguish a range by if it includes "-", no?

```
arr.forEach((val) => {
    if (val.indexOf("-") > -1) {
        // do something here
    }
})
```

For `// do something here`, you'd take what you already have and make it into a function:

```
function getArrayFromRange(range) {
    range = str.split("-");

    start = parseInt(range[0]);
    end = parseInt(range[1]);

    var rangeArray = [];

    for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
        rangeArray.push(i);
    }

    return rangeArray;
}
```

You'd call the function with your range, and then insert the values from what's returned into the appropriate place in `arr`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// the predefined array
var arr = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"];

// new array will be this
var output = [];

// loop over each item in array
for(i in arr){
  // if array has a '-' character in it
  if(arr[i].indexOf('-') > 0){
     // split the array into start and end range
     var split = arr[i].split('-');
     // loop through start and end
     for(var p = parseInt(split[0]); p < parseInt(split[1]) + 1; p++){
         // push it to the new array
         output.push(p.toString());
     }
  }else{
    // the item doesn't contain '-', push it directly
    output.push(arr[i].toString());
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you are after something like this, but maybe I am wrong:

```js
var arr = ["1", "6", "4", "9-11", "13-15"];

var output =[
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [9, 10, 11],
    [13, 14, 15]
];

var ranges = arr.map(function(item) {
    var range = item.split('-');
    if (range.length === 2) {
        var start = parseInt(range[0]);
        var end = parseInt(range[1]);
    } else {
        start = 0;
        end = parseInt(range[0]);
    }
    
    var rangeArray = [];

    for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
        rangeArray.push(i);
    }
    
    return rangeArray;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a while loop for returning the single values of the range.

```js
var array = ["1", "6", "4", "5", "9-11", "13-15"],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var p = a .split('-');
        do {
            r.push((p[0]++).toString());
        } while (p[0] <= p[1])
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```